# Click Gmail Refresh button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gmail, webbrowser-control

I am writing a simple personal app that has a browser control and I want it to automatically "Refresh" gmail to check it more often than it does by default. There are monkey scripts that do this but I'm trying to add my personal style to it.

Anyhow, I've looked around and found everything but what I can do in csharp using the browser control.

I found this:

```
// Link the ID from the web form to the Button var
theButton = webBrowser_Gmail.Document.GetElementById("Refresh");

// Now do the actual click.
theButton.InvokeMember("click");
```

But it comes back with null in 'theButton' so it doesn't invoke anything.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately gmail's Refresh button does not have the typical "Id" attribute. The markup for the button looks like the following:
<div class="J-Zh-I J-J5-Ji J-Zh-I L3" act="20" role="button" tabindex="0" style="-webkit-user-select: none; ">Refresh</div>
I am not certain as to how one would go about targeting this element.

Comment: Wonder if that was done on purpose to prevent this type of thing? That's going to really put a damper in my day if so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been awhile since I've used JavaScript, but given the other answers and comments that there is no real ID associated with the element, could you do something like the following:

1. Search all Div's with an attribute of Role == 'Button' and an InnerHtml == 'Refresh'.
2. Once the correct InnerHtml is found, get the Element.
3. Invoke the click on the found Element.

Again, this may be blowing smoke, but thought I'd throw it out there.

**edit**: Just realized you are doing this with C# and a browser control; however, the concept would still be the same.

Comment: Does the browser control offer a collection of the div that I can loop through or do I need to parse the html?

Comment: You betcha. It's called the DOM and there is ample documentation. There is jQuery which allows smart (you guessed it:) querying and if it is xhtml I reckon you can employ xpath queries

Answer (score 1):

The best suggestion I could give you at this point involves an existing API that is used for .NET web browser based automation:

http://watin.org/

Since the div tag with the desired button really only seems to identify itself with the class name, you could use the Find.BySelector(“”) code included with the most recent version of watin.